# In VBA I read from a file an excel formula and try to paste it into a cell. But it fails (nothing is written)

Tags: excel, vba, file, formula, cell

In VBA I read from a file the exact following text and is placed in variable xValue:

```
 =WEEKNUM( "14 Mar 2021"; 21 )
```

This needs to go into a Cell. I use the VBA code:

```
 Cells( nRow, nColumn).Formula2 = xValue
```

However, nothing happens to the Cell. It stays empty.
When 'normal' text is read from the file (e.g.: Hello World), it is pasted correctly when using:

```
 Cells(nRow, nColumn).Value2 = xValue
```

The variable is defined as:

```
 Dim xValue As String
```

Any hints on what may be the cause or how to get the formula into the Cell?
(the formula is 'unknown' when reading the file)

Comment: Try `.Formula2Local` instead of `.Formula2`.

Comment: Unbelievable - that works. 
Thank you !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The original problem was the `;` separator. `Formula2` expects the `,` as the separator.